# Disable automount notification for usb-drive

Tags: 12.04, gnome, notification, automount

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Shell and on my computer I have a usb-drive (with two partitions) that are always plugged in. When I login there is always a notification that they have been mounted. How do I remove that notification!?

Answer (score 5):

Run this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn off notification only, I would recommend that you [see this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=205&t=91452).

Quoted from the same site:

> You have to add an entry to /etc/fstab to ensure it is always mounted
>   during boot. Otherwise it gets automounted after you login (causing
>   the notification).

<sup>Source: [http://forums.linuxmint.com/](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=205&t=91452)</sup>